# multiple query with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to use two queries from the same database but I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set

How do I avoid this problem? Note that every table doesn't have same rows number.

Code:

```
try {
    Dbconnection NewConnect = new Dbconnection();
    Dbconnection NewConnect2 = new Dbconnection();
    Connection con = NewConnect.MakeConnect();
    Connection con2 = NewConnect2.MakeConnect();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    Statement stmt2 = con2.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from class");
    ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * from intervals");
    while (rs.next()) {
        clasess.add(rs.getString(2));
    }
    while (rs2.next()) {
        intervals.add(rs.getString(2));
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong... but I suggest you write `rs.beforeFirst()` *before* each `while` loop

Answer (score 3):

In your second `while` loop, you're calling `rs.getString` instead of `rs2.getString`.

This would be avoided if you used a more efficient setup in the first place; at the absolute minimum, you're holding the `rs2` cursor open unnecessarily during your first loop. I can't see any difference in configuration between your database connections, so just use one `Connection`, and then reuse the `Statement` and `ResultSet` variables, replacing them between `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

the Exception come from code intervals.add(rs.getString(2)); 
you should not use rs.getString(2).
the result set of rs is closed the connction with database.

i think you want use rs2,  be carefull.